# Laravel 4.x , module system able to install/enable/disable via panel?

Tags: php, laravel-4

i just started to use laravel, and i was able to create a new HMVC system following this tutorial http://creolab.hr/2013/05/modules-in-laravel-4/

i was wondering , if there a anyway to make a panel where you can install/enable/disable a module,

right now i create my "module" , but to be able to use it, i need to add the namespace in app.php , and then i need to run "composer dump-autload", in order to add this new code,

my initial plan was create a panel where i can automate this process , but when i was working in doing it, i came across that is not a easy thing to do,

1. i wanted to add the new namespace to the array inside app.php, just looking to the database and then add it, but i dont have database access
2. run composer dump-autoload is always necesary , any ideas how to
   achived this?

Answer (score 1):

Please find this 
http://packalyst.com/packages/package/levare/modules

The new version is under development

**Update**

I found this package:
https://github.com/creolab/laravel-modules